# How To Secure Third Party API data using Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I'm using a third party API Key for my website. I have done some modification on that API and now I'm using it for my own site.

I want to secure that API data by adding a restriction on any user (Authenticated or Anonymous ).

I want to add a time limit on the data provided by the API. So, if anybody uses the same data after a certain period of time then it will show an error.

As well as I want some restrictions on users IP. So, a user can access my website a fixed number of time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the Django REST Framework JWT Authentication.

I implemented https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt

It works - the installation is rather easy - read the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) use the authentication class settings. If you are using normal Django views you can wrap the view with a [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf)